# Flower shop in O'Hare?

Tags: shopping, chicago, ord

Is there a flower shop somewhere at O'Hare Airport?  If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Interesting.  Well, there was definitely some research effort... O'Hare's website doesn't list anything, and searching online didn't reveal anything that was current in the last 6 years.  I didn't bother mentioning that in the question because it wasn't relevant.  It's a pretty straightforward question... not sure what other research could possibly be involved here.  You either know the answer or you don't.  But, if you want to split hairs on rules, you can certainly do that.

Comment: @Brad It is relevant, because otherwise you're asking people to waste time on things you've already tried.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't expect people to Google for me.

Comment: @Brad You would be surprised how many do expect people to Google for them.

Comment: This is not a definitive answer, as it's been a bit more than a year since I've been through O'Hare. There are/were several, in the baggage claim areas in both Terminal 1 and Terminal 2. They're not florists but shops with other items (newspapers, etc.). And, at one time, in the O'Hare Hilton there was a sort of variety shop that had flowers; it may still be there and you could call and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O'Hare's website lists what is currently offered at the airport.  And as you discovered there is no flower shop.

Between security rules, agricultural rules and traveler's shopping preferences, flower vendors are few and far between.  Tropical destinations which are known for their flowers (Hawaii, Thailand, etc) may offer boxed cut flowers.  But most airports offer the same same shopping experience worldwide (fashion, fragrance, alcohol).

The days of picking up a bouquet of flowers while flying for the mistress at your destination are pretty much gone.

Comment: While I don't remember seeing *dedicated* flower shops at airports, having at least *some* flowers sold at non-dedicated shops is a common sight, especially in the arrivals area, where it is common to greet people with flowers. I may be misremembering about other airports, but YYZ (Toronto Pearson) definitely has some flowers in a news/general variety store in the international arrivals area. This is where I'd look in other airports as well.

Comment: I think there's a flower vending machine.  At least there was a couple years ago. If you're determined to impress, hire a limo and ask they include some flowers. I'm sure you can get that service for an exorbitant price.